# How to create config properties for tinylog at runtime with User preferences

Tags: java, logging, tinylog

I would like the user to be able to choose where the error logs in my application are sent to. I am using tinylog at the moment.

I have used their example code to configure where errors are written to (the user preference is chosen via a Swing fileChooser).

Their example is:

```
Configurator.defaultConfig()
           .writer(new FileWriter("log.txt"))
           .level(Level.WARNING)
           .activate();
```

which I have changed to:

```
Writer fwError= new FileWriter(userPrefs.get("PathForError", null),true);
Configurator.defaultConfig().writer(fwError).level(Level.WARNING).activate();
```

However I get the error as follows `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from FileWriter to Writer".`

How can I make this conversion work and why doesn't the example work?

Comment: What does `userPrefs.get("PathForError", null)`return? A String?          @Sebastian Try to change type of fwError to `FileWriter`

Comment: Yes it returns a string

Comment: Even if I use the example given I get the error The method writer(Writer) in the type Configurator is not applicable for the arguments (FileWriter)

Comment: I am personnaly using slf4j with simpleLogger, and the command is : `System.setProperty(org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.LOG_FILE_KEY, MyFilePath);` I tell you this because simpleLogger is... Simple :p

Comment: tinylogger is also simple. I want to stay with this for the moment

Comment: Why do you want an append parameter when creating the FileWriter?

Comment: I believe you are using `Writer` from other package

Comment: The signature is `Configurator.writer(org.pmw.tinylog.writers.Writer)`.  You can pass an instance of `org.pmw.tinylog.writers.FileWriter` as an argument.  But I suppose you are passing `java.io.FileWriter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org.pmw.tinylog.writers.Writer is not ancestor of java.io.FileWriter. try to use full qualified org.pmw.tinylog.writers.FileWriter()

Comment: Aha. Thanks so much.